# reading data from URL using spark databricks platform

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

trying to read data from url using spark on databricks community edition platform
i tried to use spark.read.csv and using SparkFiles but still, i am missing some simple point

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/adult.csv"
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
# sc.addFile(url)
# sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
# df = sqlContext.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("adult.csv"), header=True, inferSchema= True) 

df = spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("adult.csv"), header=True, inferSchema= True)
```

got path related error:

*`Path does not exist: dbfs:/local_disk0/spark-9f23ed57-133e-41d5-91b2-12555d641961/userFiles-d252b3ba-499c-42c9-be48-96358357fb75/adult.csv;'`*

i also tried someother way

```
val content = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/adult.csv").mkString

 # val list = content.split("\n").filter(_ != "")
   val rdd = sc.parallelize(content)
   val df = rdd.toDF

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-332010883169993>", line 16
    val content = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/adult.csv").mkString
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

data should be loaded directly to databricks folder or i should be able load directly from url using spark.read, any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above answer works but might be error prone some times SparkFiles.get will return null

*#1 is  more prominent way of getting a file from any url or public s3 location*

---

#### Option 1 :

[IOUtils.toString will do the trick see the docs of apache commons io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) jar will be already present in any spark cluster whether its databricks or any other spark installation.

Below is the scala way of doing this... I have taken a raw git hub csv file for this example ... can change based on the requirements.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils // jar will be already there in spark cluster no need to worry
import java.net.URL 

val urlfile=new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lrjoshi/webpage/master/public/post/c159s.csv")
  val testcsvgit = IOUtils.toString(urlfile,"UTF-8").lines.toList.toDS()
  val testcsv = spark
                .read.option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .csv(testcsvgit)
  testcsv.show
```

Result :

```
+-----------+------+----+----+---+-----+
|Experiment |Virus |Cell| MOI|hpi|Titer|
+-----------+------+----+----+---+-----+
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1|  0| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1|  6| 2.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 12| 2.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 24|  5.0|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 48|  5.5|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 72|  7.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1|  0| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1|  6| 3.75|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 12|  4.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 24| 3.75|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 48| 3.25|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 72| 3.25|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0|  0|  6.5|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0|  6| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 12| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 24| 6.25|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 48|  6.5|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 72|  7.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU|10.0|  0|  7.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU|10.0|  6| 4.75|
+-----------+------+----+----+---+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

#### Option 2 : in Scala

```
import java.net.URL
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
val urlfile="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lrjoshi/webpage/master/public/post/c159s.csv"
spark.sparkContext.addFile(urlfile)

val df = spark.read
.option("inferSchema", true)
.option("header", true)
.csv("file://"+SparkFiles.get("c159s.csv"))
df.show
```

**Result : Will be same as Option #1** like below

```
+-----------+------+----+----+---+-----+
|Experiment |Virus |Cell| MOI|hpi|Titer|
+-----------+------+----+----+---+-----+
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1|  0| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1|  6| 2.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 12| 2.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 24|  5.0|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 48|  5.5|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu| 0.1| 72|  7.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1|  0| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1|  6| 3.75|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 12|  4.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 24| 3.75|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 48| 3.25|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU| 0.1| 72| 3.25|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0|  0|  6.5|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0|  6| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 12| 4.75|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 24| 6.25|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 48|  6.5|
|      EXP I| C159S|OFTu|10.0| 72|  7.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU|10.0|  0|  7.0|
|      EXP I| C159S| STU|10.0|  6| 4.75|
+-----------+------+----+----+---+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

If you are using windows **`.csv("file:///`** should be used instead of `//`

#### Option 3: Use [httpclient library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html)

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object ReadFromUrl {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("ReadFromUrl")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val url = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv"
    val httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
    val httpGet = new HttpGet(url)
    val response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)
    val entity = response.getEntity
    val data = EntityUtils.toString(entity)

    val tempFile = java.io.File.createTempFile("airtravel", ".csv")
    tempFile.deleteOnExit()
    val writer = new java.io.PrintWriter(tempFile)
    writer.write(data)
    writer.close()

    val df: DataFrame = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load(tempFile.getAbsolutePath)

    df.show()
    
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Result :

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|Month| "1958"| "1959"| "1960"|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  JAN|  340.0|  360.0|  417.0|
|  FEB|  318.0|  342.0|  391.0|
|  MAR|  362.0|  406.0|  419.0|
|  APR|  348.0|  396.0|  461.0|
|  MAY|  363.0|  420.0|  472.0|
|  JUN|  435.0|  472.0|  535.0|
|  JUL|  491.0|  548.0|  622.0|
|  AUG|  505.0|  559.0|  606.0|
|  SEP|  404.0|  463.0|  508.0|
|  OCT|  359.0|  407.0|  461.0|
|  NOV|  310.0|  362.0|  390.0|
|  DEC|  337.0|  405.0|  432.0|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this.

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/adult.csv"
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)

**df = spark.read.csv("file://"+SparkFiles.get("adult.csv"), header=True, inferSchema= True)**
```

Just fetching few columns of your csv url.

```
df.select("age","workclass","fnlwgt","education").show(10);
>>> df.select("age","workclass","fnlwgt","education").show(10);
+---+----------------+------+---------+
|age|       workclass|fnlwgt|education|
+---+----------------+------+---------+
| 39|       State-gov| 77516|Bachelors|
| 50|Self-emp-not-inc| 83311|Bachelors|
| 38|         Private|215646|  HS-grad|
| 53|         Private|234721|     11th|
| 28|         Private|338409|Bachelors|
| 37|         Private|284582|  Masters|
| 49|         Private|160187|      9th|
| 52|Self-emp-not-inc|209642|  HS-grad|
| 31|         Private| 45781|  Masters|
| 42|         Private|159449|Bachelors|
+---+----------------+------+---------+
```

SparkFiles get the absolute path of the file which is local to your driver or worker. That's the reason why it was not able to find it.