# How to fix "'Path does not exist" when importing csv in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was following this tutorial (https://www.guru99.com/pyspark-tutorial.html) and trying to read the csv file with sqlContext.read.csv, but this error showed:'Path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-62c50c87-060e-49f7-b331-111abfa496f3/userFiles-da6cdfff-ea8a-426c-b4f4-fe5a15c67794/adult.csv;'

I heard that I might have to copy the file across all the nodes of same shared file system or use HDFS, but I don't know exactly how I should do these.

This is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("adult.csv"), header=True, inferSchema= True)
```

This is the result I got:

```
AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-62c50c87-060e-49f7-b331-111abfa496f3/userFiles-da6cdfff-ea8a-426c-b4f4-fe5a15c67794/adult.csv;'
```

Comment: The error message appears to think there is a semicolon after the filename.  Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: ^ thats a negative, semicolon is added by sloppy py exception formatter

Comment: @luoyang I think your tutorial should instruct you to add a file to the context first, via `sc.addFile("adult.csv")`.

Comment: @Luo Yang--Please see answer below. This can solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014043/reading-data-from-url-using-spark-databricks-platform/57019702#57019702

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the instruction on the website you pasted, do following first:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guru99-edu/R-Programming/master/adult_data.csv"
from pyspark import SparkFiles
sc.addFile(url)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Then you can load the file with `read.csv`:

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("adult.csv"), header=True, inferSchema= True)
```

`sc.addFile(url)` sets the root directory for `SparkFiles` to use in `get` function.
You can run this to check the current root directory:

```
SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()
```

It should looks like this:

```
C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-62c50c87-060e-49f7-b331-111abfa496f3/userFiles-da6cdfff-ea8a-426c-b4f4-fe5a15c67794/
```

So when you call `SparkFiles.get('adult.csv')`, Spark is looking file under that directory, that's why you saw the error message.

Another solution is to download the file, put into your local directory, and run :

```
df = spark.read.csv(your_local_path_to_adult.csv, header=True, inferSchema= True)
```