# Reading url via pyspark in Databricks notebook

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am unable to read the content of a URL via pySpark in Databricks Notebooks(Version 8.3, Spark 3.1.1). I have tried almost all the possibilities but unable to find out the exact problem. Here is my code.

```
from pyspark import SparkFiles
url = 'https://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mors_1101/tps/1998_028/8028d38a.tps'
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
df1 = spark.read.text("file://"+SparkFiles.get('8028d38a.tps'))
df1.show()
```

Here is the error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 43) (10.139.64.4 executor 0): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file file:/local_disk0/spark-95887d0f-a955-4075-86ac-520a51f0c64e/userFiles-9204e03a-a0fd-4999-9f40-9d9c3cc599a6/8028d38a.tps. It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running &#39;REFRESH TABLE tableName&#39; command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved. If Delta cache is stale or the underlying files have been removed, you can invalidate Delta cache manually by restarting the cluster.
```

I have referred [reading data from URL using spark databricks platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014043/reading-data-from-url-using-spark-databricks-platform) as an example. Did anyone face the similar problem?

Comment: did you try to delete it dbutils.fs.rm("/local_disk0/spark-95887d0f-a955-4075-86ac-520a51f0c64e", True) and run again?

Comment: @HubertDudek that did not work. The output of the above command is False.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best i've found from youtube pyspark for everyone playlist

```
!curl  "https://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mors_1101/tps/1998_028/8028d38a.tps" >> 8028d38a.tps
```

Answer (score 0):

As workaround , we can read respective location `panda dataframe` and covert into `pyspark` dataframe for further process .

```
url = 'https://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mors_1101/tps/1998_028/8028d38a.tps'
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv(url))
display(df)
```

**Screen print :**

[image]

If you want to skip first row if that is invalid one ,

[image]