# Use csv from GitHub in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Usually, to read a local `.csv` file I use this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("github_csv") \
        .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("path_to_file", inferSchema = True)
```

But trying to use a link to a `csv` raw file in github, I get the following error:

```
url_github = r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AISCIENCES/course-master-big-data-with-pyspark-and-aws/main/Code/03-Spark%20DFs/StudentData.csv"
df = spark.read.csv(url_github, inferSchema = True)

#Error
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.csv.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.AbstractHttpFileSystem.listStatus(AbstractHttpFileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpsFileSystem.listStatus(HttpsFileSystem.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.listLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.$anonfun$parallelListLeafFilesInternal$1(HadoopFSUtils.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFilesInternal(HadoopFSUtils.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:571)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014043/reading-data-from-url-using-spark-databricks-platform

Comment: @Shankar I've tried but it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` seems self-descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access external data from driver. There are some workarounds like simple using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

url_github = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AISCIENCES/course-master-big-data-with-pyspark-and-aws/main/Code/03-Spark%20DFs/StudentData.csv'


pd_df = pd.read_csv(url_github)
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)

spark_df.limit(5).show()
```

```
+---+------+----------------+------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|age|gender|            name|course| roll|marks|               email|
+---+------+----------------+------+-----+-----+--------------------+
| 28|Female| Hubert Oliveras|    DB| 2984|   59|Annika Hoffman_Na...|
| 29|Female|Toshiko Hillyard| Cloud|12899|   62|Margene Moores_Ma...|
| 28|  Male|  Celeste Lollis|    PF|21267|   45|Jeannetta Golden_...|
| 29|Female|    Elenore Choy|    DB|32877|   29|Billi Clore_Mitzi...|
| 28|  Male|  Sheryll Towler|   DSA|41487|   41|Claude Panos_Judi...|
+---+------+----------------+------+-----+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: it is kind of a shortcut yes. thanks! I'll wait if someone come up with an answer and if not, i'll mark yours as accepted